# Gradle: Missing output from shell command

Tags: macos, gradle, build.gradle

I am trying to use `ld` from within a gradle build script to get full paths to libraries within MacOS. I am trying to achieve the equivalent of the following command run in my shell manually:

```
$ ld -lboost_program_options -dylib -arch x86_64 -t
ld: warning: platform not specified
ld: warning: No platform min-version specified on command line
/usr/local/lib/libboost_program_options.dylib
```

As evident from the above, the command produced 2 warnings on stderr and the full path to a library on stdout. And the return code is zero. When I set up the same command within gradle however, the command runs successfully, and the stderr output is caught correctly, however stdout appears to be empty.

The relevant portion of the build.gradle script is:

```
    def sout = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    def serr = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    exec {
        commandLine "ld"
        args "-lboost_program_options", "-dylib", "-arch", "x86_64", "-t"
        errorOutput = serr
        standardOutput = sout
    }

    logger.debug("Out: '" + sout.toString() + "'")
    logger.debug("Err: '" + serr.toString() + "'")
```

The relevant portion of the gradle output with debugging enabled is as follows:

```
14:53:20.351 [INFO] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Starting process 'command 'ld''. Working directory: /Users/kpenev/projects/git/SuperPhot Command: ld -lboost_program_options -dylib -arch x86_64 -t
14:53:20.352 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Environment for process 'command 'ld'': {PATH=/Users/kpenev/anaconda3/bin:/Users/kpenev/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texb
in:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/kpenev/anaconda3/bin, JAVA_ARCH=x86_64, LC_TERMINAL=iTerm2, CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV=base, CONDA_EXE=/Users/kpenev/anaconda3/bin/conda, TERM=xterm-color, CONDA_PYTHON_EXE=/Users/kpenev/anaconda3/bin/python, LANG=en_US.UTF-
8, CONDA_PREFIX=/Users/kpenev/anaconda3, DISPLAY=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.Fm0FJEKcMY/org.macosforge.xquartz:0, JAVA_MAIN_CLASS_74054=org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain, ITERM_SESSION_ID=w0t2p0:DDBFD539-247F-4B0D-946E-9BEAB74DA24E,
 _CE_M=, COLORTERM=truecolor, APP_ICON_74054=/Users/kpenev/projects/git/SuperPhot/media/gradle.icns, LOGNAME=kpenev, TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION=3.3.7, PWD=/Users/kpenev/projects/git/SuperPhot, XPC_SERVICE_NAME=0, CONDA_SHLVL=1, PYTHONPATH=:/Use
rs/kpenev/projects/git/poet/PythonPackage:/Users/kpenev/projects/git/general_purpose_python_modules:/Users/kpenev/projects/git/SuperPhot/PythonPackage/:/Users/kpenev/projects/git/PhotometryPipeline, SHELL=/bin/bash, LC_TERMINAL_VERSION=3.
3.7, TERM_PROGRAM=iTerm.app, SQLITE_EXEMPT_PATH_FROM_VNODE_GUARDS=/Users/kpenev/Library/WebKit/Databases, OLDPWD=/Users/kpenev/projects/git/SuperPhot, CLICOLOR=1, USER=kpenev, VISUAL=vim, TMPDIR=/var/folders/xq/l5s9qnd10kd4m37x4dcjc3fr000
0gn/T/, ITERM_PROFILE=Default, LIBRARY_PATH=:/usr/local/gfortran/lib, SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.zuHkV3WzFC/Listeners, _CE_CONDA=, PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1, XPC_FLAGS=0x0, TERM_SESSION_ID=w0t2p0:DDBFD539-247F-4B0D-946E-9BEAB74
DA24E, APP_NAME_74054=Gradle, __CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING=0x1F5:0x0:0x0, Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.RrVbuY9yXD/Render, CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER=(base) , com.apple.java.jvmTask=CommandLine, COLORFGBG=7;0, HOME=/User
s/kpenev, SHLVL=1}
14:53:20.352 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Changing state to: STARTING
14:53:20.352 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Waiting until process started: command 'ld'.
14:53:20.356 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Changing state to: STARTED
14:53:20.356 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner] waiting until streams are handled...
14:53:20.356 [INFO] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Successfully started process 'command 'ld''
14:53:20.374 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Changing state to: SUCCEEDED
14:53:20.374 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Process 'command 'ld'' finished with exit value 0 (state: SUCCEEDED)
14:53:20.374 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.Project] Out: ''
14:53:20.375 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.Project] Err: 'ld: warning: platform not specified
ld: warning: No platform min-version specified on command line
'
```

I see from the log that the correct command ran, that it finished with zero return code, indicating success and that the warning messages on stderr are correctly caught, but mysteriously stdout appears empty, even though if I manually run the same command, stdout contains `/usr/local/lib/libboost_program_options.dylib`.

I would appreciate help with how to get this to report the correct path to the library.